# Does MS SQL Server 2008 cache binary data fields? Ie VARBINARY

Tags: sql-server, database, browser-cache

Does MS SQL Server 2008 cache binary data fields? Ie VARBINARY

We have MS SQL Server 2008 R2 using 12gb of ram constantly caching data. Our database includes over 200gb of VARBINARY. Would this be cached as well?

**EDIT:** SQL Server does indeed cache binary data Thanks @Martin

Can you tell SQL Server to stop caching binary data or to limit this somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Try

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT database_id,
                page_type,
                total_page_count = COUNT(*) OVER (),
                page_count = COUNT(*) OVER 
                                     (PARTITION BY database_id, page_type),
                row_num = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                                     (PARTITION BY database_id, page_type 
                                          ORDER BY (SELECT 0))
         FROM   sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors)
SELECT page_type,
       page_count,
       PercentageOfCache = ROUND(1E2 * page_count / total_page_count, 2),
       SizeInCache =
       CASE
         WHEN page_count > 131072 
              THEN LTRIM(STR(page_count / 131072.0) + ' GB')
         WHEN page_count > 128 
              THEN LTRIM(STR(page_count / 128.0) + ' MB')
         ELSE LTRIM(STR(page_count * 8) + ' KB')
       END
FROM   T
WHERE  database_id = DB_ID()
       AND row_num = 1
ORDER  BY page_count DESC
```

To see how many of each type of page are currently in the buffer cache for your database.

Dedicated LOB page types are `TEXT_MIX_PAGE` and `TEXT_TREE_PAGE` but LOB data can also be stored on data pages.

Comment: @Richard `TEXT_MIX_PAGE` and `TEXT_TREE_PAGE` - I think there might be one other type I'm forgetting as well - just looking in the SQL Server Internals book...

Comment: Nope. That's it I think for LOB pages. `TEXT_DATA` and `TEXT_TREE_PAGE` are the same thing [as far as I can see](http://sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/Inside-the-Storage-Engine-Anatomy-of-a-page.aspx) varbinary(max) can be stored in page if small enough.

Comment: Thank you. The next question is how can i tell SQL to not cache binary data as its currently caching 4gb of binary data.

Comment: The table that has the binary data has 3931mb buffered data. :(

Comment: @Jeremy - I'm not sure about that one. The cache eviction policy should automatically drop those pages eventually if they are not being used and it needs to bring in new pages.

Comment: @Martin - Thank you so much for your valuable time.